# Loading padding/margin from different SCSS file

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to load property from class from different scss file? This side scss file is imported to main scss file. All properties are inherited, but margins, paddings, font styles not. Browser is not willing to load these properites. Are there any rules with extend?

**Side scss file:**

```
.section-headline {
    font-size: em(30);
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: auto;
    
    color: $main-col-text;

    margin-bottom: em(20);
}
```

**Main scss file:**

```
.i-headline {
        @extend .section-headline;
    }
```

Comment: What type of element is `.i-headline`? If it's an `inline` element - margin and padding will not be applied.

Comment: @disinfor It is H1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your `em()` function is imported somewhere ?

Answer (score 1):

In SASS you can declare classes in one file and import them into another without any problem, just make sure your import is done properly. And yes you can use `@extend` to access the rules of your imported selector.

Also try `display: inline-block;` and see if your margin/padding are working. Maybe you were trying to apply them to an inline element.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I have one scss file where are imported all scss sub-files. It looks like this:

```
@import 'gClass';
@import 'buttons';
@import 'general';
@import 'mixins';
@import 'typography';
@import 'pages/home';
```

In sub-file gClass is my class **.section-headline**. In **pages/home** is scss code with **i-headline** class. I tried to copy **.section-headline** to main scss file mentioned upper. In this case it works, but if i try to have **.section-headline** in gClass file, it doesnt.